# What is concept of temperture in ion trap?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature

As only several thousands of particles are holding in the ion trap, how can we understand the temperature?

Comment: Average energy per particle.

Answer (score 1):

It's already quite classical. The particles are all close enough to be interacting, so you have O(N*N) interactions - millions of pairs, for thousands of particles. Also, since you have magnetic confinement, you don't need supercold environments. The ion energies are well above the ground state, so the Pauli exclusion principle isn't directly important.

Answer (score 0):

In [the kinetic theory of gases,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Temperature#Kinetic_theory_of_gases) temperature is identified with the root means square of the kinetic energy of the molecules/particles.

[image: temperature]

Where k is the Bolzmann constant.

The thousand are enough for an rms  value of their velocity.

Comment: *"temperature is identified with the root means square of the kinetic energy of the molecules/particles"* -- it's the mean-square of the velocities, or the mean energy.